# Bootstrap 3.6 - Div with 100% height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, gallery

I took a CSS image gallery (https://codepen.io/gabrielajohnson/pen/EMVxEL) which I would like to use in my project.

The problem is the gallery uses `html,body {width:100%,height:100%}` which works as expected. But in my case the gallery is in a Bootstrap Modal where `height: 100%` is not working and it gives me a **0 height**. I can't use a height in px, because I don't know how many items gallery has.

Do you have some ideas how could I fixed it? I tried to use `min-height:100%, height:100%` in the modal window, but without result.

Here is my CodePen example: https://codepen.io/Piticu/pen/zYYLrKY

Answer (score 0):

You'll find below a basic html snippet with the corresponding css for an 100% modal height in Bootstrap 3. Use this as the main structure and build up your image gallery in the modal body.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h3>The Large Modal</h3>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lgModal">
    Click to open Modal </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="lgModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lgModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Large Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="gallery">
          GALLERY <!-- here your gallery -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

With this css

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
}
body > .container,
body > .container-fluid {
  min-height: 100%; 
}
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top:5%; bottom:5%; /* see .modal-dialog below */
  height: auto;
}
.modal-dialog {
  /* 100% - top 5% - bottom 5% */
  height: 90%;
}
.modal-content {
  height: 100%;
}
.modal-body {
  /* 100% - heightModalFooter */
  height: calc(100% - 160px);
}
.gallery {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee; /* remove this line, for test only */
}
```